# React to updates on ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, reactiveui, icommand

I have the following piece of code:

```cs
ReactiveCommand
    .CreateFromTask(_ => GetPerson())
    .Execute()
    .Subscribe(x => person = x);

var canNext = person?.Friends
                .ToObservableChangeSet()
                .AutoRefresh(x => x.Selected)
                .ToCollection()
                .Select(x => x.Any(y => y.Selected));

MyCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async _ => Debug.Write("Hello"), canNext);
```

How can I get `canNext` to update in order to disable/enable my command?

If I hard code a `person` with `friends` the `canNext` works fine when selecting and deselecting friends. However when assigning `person` to an `async` call `GetPerson()` it breaks any updates running to `canNext`.

I've created a dummy project to help demo the problem. https://github.com/grierson/updateButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to fix?

To get the behavior you want you could first initialize `person`, and then when you call `GetPerson()`, just update the `person` you already have, as follows

```cs
person = new Person() { Friends = new ObservableCollection<Friend>() };

ReactiveCommand
    .CreateFromTask(_ => GetPerson())
    .Execute()
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        foreach (var friend in x.Friends)
        {
            person.Friends.Add(friend);
        }
    });

var canNext = person?.Friends
    .ToObservableChangeSet()
    .AutoRefresh(x => x.Selected)
    .ToCollection()
    .Select(x => x.Any(y => y.Selected));

MyCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async _ => Debug.Write("Hello"), canNext);
```

Now some words about what you are doing wrong:

### Why button is not changing?

The reason for this behavior is that when you run

```cs
ReactiveCommand
    .CreateFromTask(_ => GetPerson())
    .Execute()
    .Subscribe(x => person = x);

var canNext = person?.Friends
    .ToObservableChangeSet()
    .AutoRefresh(x => x.Selected)
    .ToCollection()
    .Select(x => x.Any(y => y.Selected));

MyCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async _ => Debug.Write("Hello"), canNext);
```

at the moment you reach the line that sets `MyCommand`, the value of `canNext` is `null`: this happens because `person` is `null` at that point of time, and so you are passing a `null` value to the `canExecute` parameter of `CreateFromTask`, i.e. you are really setting

```cs
MyCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async _ => Debug.Write("Hello"), null);
```

or what is the same

```cs
MyCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async _ => Debug.Write("Hello"));
```

that is, you are not really passing any information to `canExecute`, and the `Button` is simply always active, as you can see when you run the code above.

**P.S.**: Thanks for the simple sample. It was key on being able to find out the root of the problem.